# Androidでjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: android, java

Androidで実装中に、以下のようなExceptionが発生します。

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: "アプリ名", PID: 19962
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver "ClassA": java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class "ClassA"
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2441)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class "ClassA"
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2436)
    ... 10 more
```

ソースコード
BroadcastReceiver

```
public abstract class ClassA extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ClassA() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        String actionName = intent.getAction();
        if (actionName.equals("A")) {
        }
    }
}
```

送信元

```
public static void sendBroadcast(final Context context, Serializable obj) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("A");
        intent.putExtra("key", obj);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

マニフェスト

```
<receiver android:name=".ClassA" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="A" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

IntentにSerializableをimplementsしたクラスをputExtraして送信しています。
端末はAndroid 4.4.4を使用しています。

対処法がわかる方教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

クラスの宣言が抽象クラスだからです。

Javaの基礎的な話として、抽象クラスはインスタンス化できません。

```
public class ClassA extends BroadcastReceiver
```

`abstract`にする必然性がなければ、クラスの宣言を上のようにすれば解決します。

Comment: 初歩的なところが理解できてなかったです。ありがとうございます。